# Use Of $slice Query while fetching data from mongodb in JAVA

Tags: java, database, mongodb

I have a small query which is giving the result while invoking it on mongo database. But when I am using this in JAVA for fetching the data then it giving me exception.

Below is the query :

```
db.collectionName.find({'name': 'Sam'},{"Address": { "$slice": -1 } })
```

In database, name is the key and address is the list containing lets say 4 number of addresses.We want to fetch the updated address in "Address" KEY.

Below is the java code which we are using :

```
final DBCollection dbCollection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("apMonitoringData");
        final BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("name", "sam");
        query.put("address", new BasicDBObject("$slice", -1));
        final BasicDBObject sortQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        // Sorting in Descending order for last updated entry
        sortQuery.put("_id", -1);
        final DBCursor dbCursor = dbCollection.find(query).sort(sortQuery).limit(1);

        DBObject dbObject = null;
        while (dbCursor.hasNext()) {
            dbObject = dbCursor.next();
        }
        return dbObject;
```

but it is giving error as

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: unknown operator: $slice
```

Can anybody please look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to separate the query from the fields.

Also, use `append` when you want to add entries to a document instead of `put`

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("name","sam");
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("address",new BasicDBObject("$slice", -1));
collection.find(query,fields).sort(sortQuery).limit(1);
```

Comment: Same error is coming.
com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: unknown operator: $slice

Comment: it is woking.
Thanks

Comment: consider please to upvote or accept my answer, thanks.